# Disable Google Search Snackbar on PWA (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps

When I highlight text on my PWA that is installed and not running directly through Chrome, a snackbar appears on the bottom of the screen with google search results (on Android at least):

[image]

Can that be disabled in Javascript? Sorry if there is already a question on this. I don't know what that thing is actually called in order to get decent search results.

Comment: The UI pattern is called [bottom sheet](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom) vs a [snackbar](https://material.io/components/snackbars) which is just used for notifications.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I'm still not finding much information on that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this on my app and worked:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

  body * {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  }

}
```